# get index of elements in a list with custom extension method

Tags: c#, .net

I have a of list of an object of type 'student' (this is a simple example).

```
public class Student
{
    string FirstName
    string Surname
    int Age
}
```

What I want to do is get a list which contain the index number of any student who is aged 20 from my list. Do I need to create a custom extension method to do this? I know I could create a loop but for this situation I do not want to.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> IndexsWhere<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        int index = 0;

        foreach (T element in source)
        {
            if (predicate(element))
                yield return index;
        }
        index++;
    }
}


List<int> test = stdList.IndexsWhere(std => std.Age == 7).ToList();
```

This returns me a list of two integers (which is correct) but both element in the list are 0 not the index numbers 2 & 5. I'm not sure if I'm using the predicate in the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misplaced `index++`. Change it to:

```
 foreach (T element in source)
        {
            if (predicate(element))
                yield return index;
            index++;
        }
```

***By the way,*** you can select indices which match the predicate like that also:

```
var result = stdList.Select((x, index) => new {Index = index, Student = x})
                    .Where(x=> x.Student.Age == 7)
                    .Select(x => x.Index).ToList();
```

But, it is better to use extension method for such purpose.

Comment: Getting the index of the *already filtered sequence* isn't going to be helpful.  He's looking for the index of the item in the *unfiltered* sequence.

Comment: @Servy Thanks for comment, I have updated my answer with the working version of this approach.

Answer (score 2):

Your increment is outside of your loop. You need to move it inside.

```
foreach (T element in source)
{
    if (predicate(element))
        yield return index++;
}
```